# Can we create different databases and admin panel for each customer from for a custom ecommerce product?

Tags: php, e-commerce

I am creating multiple eCommerce stores but want to use the same development environment for all of them. Therefore, I want to use the same project folder for all the stores as they are going to run the same code. So, is it possible guys?

However, I have assigned a different store to different admins. So, the admin panel would be unique to the store owners. If one person uploads his products, only he can manage them from his admin panel. Other store owners cannot see their products in their admin panel.

I have also assigned different databases to all the store admins so that the stores can be managed from their respective admin panels identified by the database they were assigned.

Anybody can help me to learn about how to run multiple stores from single project folder with different databases as well as different admins?

Answer (score 0):

You can set that up using environment variables in config files for each domain.

If you're using Apache, your domain specific files will be stored in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled folder. You can create a separate config for each domain. For example, if you're hosting 2 separate stores: store-one.mydomain.com and store-two.mydomain.com, you'd have 2 config files: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/store-one.mydomain.com.config and /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/store-two.mydomain.com.config

Their content would look something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName store-one.mydomain.com
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
    
    # This is where your website's code is actually located on the server.
    # This is the same for all stores.
    DocumentRoot /var/www/my-store

    # Logs from all stores would be combined. You can have them separated
    # by using store name: ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-store-one.log
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # This part should also be the same for all stores
    <Directory /var/www/my-store>
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
        Options FollowSymlinks
    </Directory>
    
    # This is different for every store. In PHP code, you can read these vars
    # and connect to different databases, while using the same source code
    # for every store.
    SetEnv DB_HOST 127.0.0.1:3306
    SetEnv DB_NAME store-one
    SetEnv DB_USER store-one-user
    SetEnv DB_PASS store-one-password
</VirtualHost>
```

In PHP, you can use `$_ENV` superglobal array to get environment variables for each store. For example `$_ENV['DB_HOST']` should get you the hostname of the database for the website that's running the code.

I'm not proficient in NGINX config, but I know that something similar can be done there as well.